# Limit sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $X=(x_n)$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such
>   that $\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$. Show that for some $r$ with
>   $0<r<1$ and some $C>0$, then we have $0<x_n<Cr^n$ for all sufficently
>   large $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Use this to show that $\text{lim}(x_n)=0$. Similarly, show that $\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)>1$ is not bounded and hence not convergent.

Since I know that $\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$ and that $0<r<1$, then I have
$0<\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)\le r<1$, but I get stuck now completing the proof.

Comment: Have you studied *infinite* series already? I ask because of your tagging...

Comment: @DonAntonio I have prior to this class, but the book asks to prove it by definition by using neighborhoods and such. Maybe I should add the real analysis tag as well.

Comment: I think the tagging is fine, and I asked about series because with them the proof of your question is almost immediate.

Comment: For all sufficiently large $n$, say $n > N$, we get $x_{n+1}/x_n < r$. So $x_{n+1} < x_n r$. By induction we get $x_{n+1} < x_nr < x_{n-1}r^2 < \cdots < x_N r^{n-N}$. Now the claim follows with $C = x_N/r^N$.

Comment: @William Will induction be the only way to show that $C = x_N/r^N$? Is there a way to show it by using definitions of neighborhoods, bounded?

Comment: You are using definition of convergence to ensure that for all sufficiently large $n$ you have $x_{n+1}/x_n < r < 1$. Other than that, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

> Since I know that $\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$ and that $0<r<1$, then I have
>   $0<\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)\le r<1$, but I get stuck now completing the proof.

You do know that $\lim\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$, but you do **not** know that $0<r<1$: you are supposed to be **proving** that there is some real number $r$ such that $0<r<1$ (and $r$ has other properties as well).

Start by using the definition of the limit of a sequence. Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$. Then by the definition of limit you know that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-L\right|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$. Let $r=\frac12(L+1)$; then $L<r<1$. (Why?) Let $\epsilon=r-L$; certainly $\epsilon>0$, so we know that $$\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-L\right|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$. But the inequality $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$L-\epsilon<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<L+\epsilon=r\;,$$

so we now know that $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<r$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$. Let

$$C=\frac{x_{n_\epsilon}}{r^{n_\epsilon}}\;;$$

Then $x_{n_\epsilon}=Cr^{n_\epsilon}$, and I leave it to you to show that $x_n<Cr^n$ for all $n>n_\epsilon$. Since $0<r<1$, we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}Cr^n=0$, and since $0<x_n<Cr^n$ for all $n>n_\epsilon$, it then follows from the squeeze theorem that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

Comment: Beautiful! Proceeding with the correct logical terminology is what I was having the most trouble with, but this is going to be very helpful in providing me a starting path to proceed with these types of questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Q.matin: You’re welcome!

Comment: Brian, quick question why did you let $r=\frac12(L+1)$?

Comment: @Q.matin: Any number strictly between $L$ and $1$ would work equally well; I just chose the number halfway between because it was easy. (Remember, the arithmetic mean of two numbers is halfway between them.)

Comment: Brian, I am a bit confused. We have that $L-\epsilon<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<L+\epsilon=r\;,$ which is why $L<r<1$, correct? Also, since $n>n_\epsilon$ why did you let $C=\frac{x_{n_\epsilon}}{r^{n_\epsilon}}$ ?

Comment: @Q.matin: (1) No. I chose an $r$ satisfying $L<r<1$. I also know (by the definition of limit) that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon$ such that $L-\epsilon<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<L+\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge n_\epsilon$. After choosing $r$, I chose $\epsilon=r-L$ and made use of the foregoing fact. (2) Because it works. If I give $C$ that value, then it’s true that $x_n\le Cr^n$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$ and $x_n<Cr^n$ for all $n>n_\epsilon$.

Comment: I would have never seen why $L<r<1$ until after half way done with the proof. Is that okay, or was I suppose to see that right from the start? Also, I still am confused why $C=\frac{x_{n_\epsilon}}{r^{n_\epsilon}}$ and why it will satisfy $x_n\le Cr^n$ for example why wouldn't $C=x_n{_{\epsilon}}$ satisfy it?

Comment: @Q.matin: (1) Are you asking how I knew that I’d have to choose an $r$ between $L$ and $1$? I know that it has to be less than $1$, because that’s given as a requirement. I know that it has to be greater than $L$, because if it weren’t there’d be no way to make $r^n$ grow faster than $x_n$. Think about the extreme case in which $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$ for all $n$: then $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a geometric sequence proportional to $L^n$, so for some $C$ we have $x_n=CL^n$ for all $n$. To get $x_n<Cr^n$, I need $r>L$. To find the proof, you have to recognize early on that the fact ...

Comment: ... that the ratios of consecutive terms are approaching a constant says that for large $n$ the sequence is almost geometric and should behave almost like a geometric sequence with ratio $L$. (2) With my $C$ you obviously have $x_{n_\epsilon}=Cr^{n_\epsilon}$. And since $r>\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ for $n\ge n_\epsilon$, it follows immediately that $$x_{n_\epsilon+1}=x_{n_\epsilon}\cdot\frac{x_{n_\epsilon+1}}{x_{n_\epsilon}}=Cr^{n_\epsilon}\frac{x_{n_\epsilon+1}}{x_{n_\epsilon}}<Cr^{n_\epsilon}\cdot r=C^{n_\epsilon+1}\;.$$ A similar calculation is the induction step to show the desired inequality.

Comment: I understand $(1)$ now, but I am sorry for my ignorance, I am still having trouble understanding $(2)$. How did you get that $x_{n_\epsilon}=Cr^{n_\epsilon}$, I cant see why that is obvious?

Comment: @Q.matin: I defined $C$ by the formula $$C=\frac{x_{n_\epsilon}}{r^{n_\epsilon}}\;;$$ just multiply both sides by the denominator.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your first comment. So much information for my brain to process all at once. Thanks again, I understand now with your help!

Comment: @Q.matin: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Write the definition of $\ell=lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ and choose $\varepsilon$ such that $r=\ell+\varepsilon<1$.